# discord.js: ReferenceError: embed is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const { checkUrl } = require("check-url");
const Discord = require("discord.js");


module.exports = async (bot, client) => {
  console.log("Successfully logged in!");
const ok = function ok(res) {
    if(res.ok == false) {
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Ramnet Status", bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor("#7289da")
        .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setFooter("Last Updated")
        .setTimestamp()
        if(res.ok == false) {
          embed.setDescription(`- Bot: <:offline:825589358270349374> Offline\n- Dashboard: :offline: Offline\n- Modmail (Support System): <:offline:825589414628950046> Offline`)
          embed.setFooter(`yes`)
        } else {
          embed.setDescription(`- Bot: :online: Online\n- Dashboard: <:offline:825589414628950046> Online\n- Modmail (Support System): <:offline:825589414628950046> Online`)
        }
    }
  }

// wrap the code below in a setInterval function so it runs every 30 seconds or so
setInterval (function () {
  checkUrl('https://mUdollar1cB0t.bencofficial.repl.co')
    .then((res) => ok(res))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err.message));
    bot.channels.cache.get('825589791441420361').send(embed);
            }, 1 * 30000); 

  };
```

bot.channels.cache.get('825589791441420361').send(embed); this is where the issue it

ReferenceError: embed is not defined
can u pls help me, this is hard for me and I would like to get it up and running

Comment: `const` is block scoped, so it's only available inside `if(res.ok == false) {}`. I also don't know why you'd check `if (res.ok == false)` inside `if (res.ok == false)`

Comment: Check your embed by using `console.log(embed)` inside and outside the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You used embed as `const` inside the function. It has to be outside the function.

Try this:

```js
module.exports = async (bot, client) => {
  console.log("Successfully logged in!");

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
  const ok = function ok(res) {
    if(res.ok == false) {
      embed 
        .setAuthor("Ramnet Status", bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor("#7289da")
        .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setFooter("Last Updated")
        .setTimestamp()
        if(res.ok == false) {
          embed.setDescription(`- Bot: <:offline:825589358270349374> Offline\n- Dashboard: :offline: Offline\n- Modmail (Support System): <:offline:825589414628950046> Offline`)
          embed.setFooter(`yes`)
        } else {
          embed.setDescription(`- Bot: :online: Online\n- Dashboard: <:offline:825589414628950046> Online\n- Modmail (Support System): <:offline:825589414628950046> Online`)
        }
    }
  }

// wrap the code below in a setInterval function so it runs every 30 seconds or so
     setInterval (function () {
       checkUrl('https://mUdollar1cB0t.bencofficial.repl.co')
         .then((res) => ok(res))
         .catch((err) => console.error(err.message));
       bot.channels.cache.get('825589791441420361').send(embed);
     }, 1 * 30000); 
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you define the `embed` variable inside a function and try to use it outside of it. A quick solution would be to return the `embed` from the function and add an extra `.then()` method that receives it so you can safely call `.send(embed)`. Check out my example below (I also fixed your `ok` function):

```js
const { checkUrl } = require('check-url');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async (bot, client) => {
  console.log('Successfully logged in!');

  function isResOK(res) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor('Ramnet Status', bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setColor('#7289da')
      .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setFooter('Last Updated')
      .setTimestamp();

    return res.ok
      ? embed
        .setDescription(`- Bot: :online: Online\n- Dashboard: <:offline:825589414628950046> Online\n- Modmail (Support System): <:offline:825589414628950046> Online`)
      : embed
        .setDescription(`- Bot: <:offline:825589358270349374> Offline\n- Dashboard: :offline: Offline\n- Modmail (Support System): <:offline:825589414628950046> Offline`)
        .setFooter(`yes`);
  }

  // wrap the code below in a setInterval function so it runs every 30 seconds or so
  setInterval(function () {
    checkUrl('https://mUdollar1cB0t.bencofficial.repl.co')
      .then((res) => isResOK(res))
      .then((embed) => bot.channels.cache.get('825589791441420361').send(embed))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err.message));
  }, 1 * 30000);
};
```